# Export Azure .bacpac to MySql .sql

Tags: mysql, azure, import, export, bacpac

Is there a solution to retrieve a base Azure, and import it into MySQL?

I have recover a .bacpac but I can't find a possibility to convert .sql
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll have to restore it to a local MS database server and then use one of the many third-party MSSQL-to-MySQL migration tools.

Comment: l appears that export of a base Azure in a standard format is very difficult!

Comment: Another possibility might be to use some migration tool to connect to the azure DB directly and copy data from there. But yes, bacpacs seem to be MS-proprietary.